# Почему деревья сажают?

Tags: употребление-слов

Сажают на стул, в крайнем случае — в тюрьму. Но почему дерево или, скажем, огурцы тоже сажают? Они же не сидят, они растут))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сесть,сидеть, садить, - от праслав. *sesti-*sedti- принять сидячее положение,потом появилось значение(в связи с появлением слова сад,усадьба)"зарыть в землю корни, зёрна", исходя из древнего смысла"принять устойчивое положение, крепко сесть, зацепиться за землю";насаждать, осадок, сажа - от него же.Сосед, заседание, председатель, селО, даже сало(то, что насело на мясо) - исторически однокоренные.

Поэтому и дерево, и огурцы сажают, т.е. укрепляют  в земле или прикрепляют к земле . Даже деталь можно"посадить", прикрепить к чему-то.